# Convert U3D to STL or OBJ file format

Tags: 3d, u3d

I want to convert universal 3d file format(.u3d) to .stl or .obj format. I am looking for some libraries to extract geometrical data(vertices, normals), materials, textures from u3d file. U3d format has become obsolete now a days. I tried searching on the internet for some libraries but was not able to find any suitable one. Is their any library available which does convert u3d to stl or obj directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, there is no direct converter available. There is an open source library in C [Universal 3D Sample Software](https://sourceforge.net/projects/u3d/) developed by Intel. This library contains a sample u3d parser and utilities to interact with u3d file format. The library can be used to extract necessary geometrical data from file which can then be converted into ASCII stl or obj format. The only drawback is this library in no longer actively managed and development stopped long back at 2007.